# What is the difference between class, object and structure in Javascript? (2016 update)

Tags: javascript, oop

Okay, I think I know the answer for ***structure:*** it’s an *object* ([set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of elements) without *methods* (function pointers) among its *fields* (elements). Right?

### ⁂

This question was [asked 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450781/difference-between-a-class-and-an-object-in-javascript) but answers are long-winded, vague (unnecessarily theoretical), make [incredible claims that Javascript has no classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and make no mention of the Javascript keyword `class`.

I’d rather ask for an update but Stack Exchange has no obvious way to request new answers to old questions. I imagine asking for updates is one of those insider features purposefully hidden from new and anonymous users.

Comment: `class` is just a fancy keyword in ES2015. It uses `prototypes` under the hood. So the answers on that _6 years old_ question still stands.

Comment: @Tushar: `⁂` = [asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(typography)). Basically, anonymous chapter (text section) title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Objects and Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450759/javascript-objects-and-classes)

Answer (score 3):

- **you do not have classes or structures in JavaScript.**
- **All you have are functions that might behave like classes and objects that are variables such as Boolean, number and string.**

Comment: That’s what I suspected. But, if so, how do I assign a constructor to `s` (defined as `var s = {a: 6, b: 7}`) and why can’t I? I tried `s.constructor`, `s.prototype.constructor` and `s.__proto__.constructor` (`= function (alert("Hello.")`). Each method failed in various ways and neither `s()` nor `new s()` worked afterwards (“Uncaught TypeError: s is not a function” and “not a constructor” respectively).

Comment: JavaScript is not object oriented programming that's why.

Comment: Meant  `= function () {alert("Hello.");}` in my last comment.

Comment: Doesn’t error message “`s` is not a function” directly contradict your claim that all Javascript variables are basically functions?

Comment: Also, if JS is not OOP ∧ I’m not allowed to set `constructor` ∧ “`s` is not a function”, what is the purpose of property `__proto__` with a `constructor` in it in every variable?