# Javascript: Objects and Classes

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

Earlier in js, we were able to do this:

```
var emptyObj = {};
```

this created an empty object, but this object is an instance of which class or is there something that I'm missing?
The concept of classes has been introduced in es6 then how were we able to define objects in es5 and earlier without the presence of a class (as objects are nothing but an instance of a class)?
Please clarify!

Comment: [Docs @ MDN might help you.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

Comment: https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: @Jonasw unable to find those can you guide?

Comment: _"objects are nothing but an instance of a class"_ That's not true.

Answer (score 6):

> ...but this object is an instance of which class...?

`Object`, but keep reading...

> The concept of classes has been introduced in es6...

Not really. ES2015 (aka "ES6") adds *`class` syntax*, but it doesn't add the concept of classes. ES5 and ES2015 both have the *concept* of classes (groups of objects with commonality), and neither has classes in the sense of class-based OOP languages like Java or C#.

JavaScript has prototypical inheritance, and overlaid on that it has *constructor functions*. When you use `new` with a constructor function, `new` creates an object that uses the object referenced by the function's `prototype` property as its prototype.

```
var emptyObj = {};
```

does the same thing

```
var emptyObj = new Object();
```

does, assuming that `Object` there has its default value.

ES2015's `class` syntax just makes it easier to define constructors and the object assigned to their `prototype` property. This ES5 code

```
function Foo(value) {
    this.value = value;
}
Foo.prototype.squared = function() {
    return this.value * this.value;
};
```

and this ES2015 code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    squared() {
        return this.value * this.value;
    }
}
```

both create a `Foo` constructor function and an object assigned to `Foo.prototype` with `squared` on it. There are a couple of minor differences (mostly to support `super`), but it's still the same prototypical inheritance with constructor functions overlaid on it whether in ES5 or ES2015.