# How are array methods aware of the values they are called on?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me how are array methods aware of the value that we called them on,
As part of the prototype inheritance shouldn't it exist on the Array.prototype
if we say

```
let animals = ['dog','cat']
animals.map( x => console.log(x))
//dog
//cat
```

I just don't understand how is map aware of that we passed ['dog','cat'].
I usually see that if you call a function then you need to call it like map(animals).

[image: So if x is an array shouldn't it exists on Array.prototype so then we can call map on it ?]

thank you in advance

or looking at the map polyfill where is the line that we assign it to the arguments of the array.

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }


    var O = Object(this);


    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }


    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = arguments[1];
    }


    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;


      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];


        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);



        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

Comment: It's the magic of JavaScript prototypal inheritance, coupled with the rules for how `this` gets set in a function call.

Comment: Why downvote this question ?

Comment: `Array​.prototype​.map()` no different than any other method that is assigned to an object.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map `arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {`

Comment: "everything is an object" in js. in this case your animals variable holds an object of type `Array`. It just happens that this object has a function called `map`. Take a look at the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and maybe considers starting with js from scratch with a good book.

Comment: Do you know how normal methods are aware of the object they are called on? Like `obj.f()` on `const obj = { x: 1, f() { console.log(this); }};`?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev not my downvote, but absolutely justified imho because the question implicates no the tinies bit of effort from OP

Comment: this makes sense `obj.f()` but in here no arguments are passed.

Comment: @JSLover why would arguments change what `this` points to in a method?

Comment: "*I usually see that if you call a function then you need to call it like map(animals).*" but you are calling a *method* - this is different from a function. A method uses the object instance you're calling it on as the context, so you don't have to pass in what it operates *on*.

Comment: so this method lives on the Array.prototype and then it checks what called it?

Comment: @JSLover Yes, exactly. The method looks (very simplified) like `function map(callback) { const res = []; for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) res[i] = callback(this[i]); return res; }`

Comment: @Bergi so this in that function will refer to what ?

Comment: @JSLover When you call the function on an array, to the array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.mymap = function(callback) {
 var myArray = this; // here is the magic
 var newArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(callback(myArray[i]));
 }
 
 return newArray;
};

console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].mymap(a => a * 2));
```

Comment: so if I am looking at the actual map poly fill, can you point out the magic bits as you did here. `var O = Object(this);`

Comment: @JSLover The `Object()` call usually does nothing, you can equally write `var O = this;`. It handles the edge case when the method is called on a primitive (non-object) value, such as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well if we looked at the definition of Map according to W3Schools:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   function for every array element.

So the function map checks every element and does something with that.
In this example you say: "Console.log every element in this array"

So it's logic that the function map is aware what is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` is a method of the `Array` object. In JavaScript, we say that the `animals` object uses "prototypical inheritance" of the `Array` object. It's kind of like saying `animals` inherits the properties and method of the `Array` base class (if you come from a world of OOP).

Since `map` is a function that exists for all `Array` objects, `animals` is no exception.

By definition `map()` takes a function, and returns an `Array`. It then iterates through each element of the array it was called from (in this case the `animals` array), and applies the passed function to each element.

Usually you would use this with a `return` statement in order to generate a new array. For instance, you could write something like:

`var upperCaseAnimals = animals.map(x => return(x.toUpperCase()))`

This would create a new array, `upperCaseAnimals` which contains all elements of the `animals` array with `toUpperCase()` applied to them.

But you can also use it to "do something" with each element of the array. This is what's being done in the sample above. Instead of giving a return value for each element, you're just `console.log()`ing each element.

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong. It tries to simplify inheritance but...there is no need to. `animals` *is* an array - inheritance is irrelevant to the behaviour. The final sentence, if transferred to Java would read like "when you do `Person p = new Person()` then `p` inherits the methods from the base `Person` class" which is NOT what happens there, nor what happens here. `p` *is* a `Person` and *has* all the methods, doesn't inherit them. Similarly, `animals` *is* an array. Inheritance would come into play with subclasses.

Comment: `animals` is not an array. `animals` is its own object. JavaScript doesn't have types. You can't make the comparison to Java because Java does have types. There is no such thing as a "class" in JavaScript.

Comment: I disagree `Array.isArray(animals)` will return `true` because it's an array. It's "it's own object" as much as `p` is - both are *instances*. You seem to confuse class and instance here.

Comment: `Array.isArray(animals)` checks if `animals.Prototype === 'Array'`. If you don't believe me you can check JS source yourself ^^

Comment: By the way I struggled with this for a very long time. This thread really helped me understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450781/difference-between-a-class-and-an-object-in-javascript